# Calling a method on a generic type in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust, and a bit confused about the usage of generic types.

Consider the below scenario:

I can create a Date type like so:

```rust
use chrono::prelude::*;

fn main() {
  let date = Utc.ymd(2021, 1, 1);
}
```

Now if I create a function `foo` to do something similar:

```rust
use chrono::prelude::*;

fn foo<Tz: TimeZone>(date: Date<Tz>) {
  let other_date = Tz.ymd(2020, 1, 1);
}


fn main() {
  let date = Utc.ymd(2021, 1, 1);

  foo(date);
}
```

I expected `Tz` to be substituted by `Utc`, and `Tz.ymd` to be equivalent to `Utc.ymd`, but it's not so:

```
error[E0423]: expected value, found type parameter `Tz`
 --> src/main.rs:4:20
  |
4 |   let other_date = Tz.ymd(2020, 1, 1);
  |                    ^^ not a value
```

Which makes me think it needs to be instantiated first? But how come that wasn't needed in the first place? What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: `Tz::ymd(date, 2021, 1, 1)`

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do and why

Comment: I ran into this in a more complex situation, and I tried to boil it down to simpler one. While the situation itself doesn't make much sense, I hope it still conveys the source of my confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`chrono::offset::Utc`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/offset/struct.Utc.html) is a [unit-like struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/structs.html). This means that it is both the name of a type with a single value and the name of the value itself, like `()` is both a type and a value. This is a convenience feature but it can sometimes be confusing.

In `Utc.ymd(2021, 1, 1)` you are using `Utc` as a value. Only values can use `.` syntax.¹ However, in `foo`, `Tz` is a type parameter. It could be any type that implements `TimeZone`, so you can't create a *value* of type `Tz` out of thin air. However, what you *can* do is take the [`timezone`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/struct.Date.html#method.timezone) of the `Date<Tz>` which was passed in:

```
fn foo<Tz: TimeZone>(date: Date<Tz>) {
    let other_date = date.timezone().ymd(2020, 1, 1);
}
```

This clones the `Tz` that is part of `date` and uses the clone to create `other_date`.

---

¹ The fully-qualified version of `Utc.ymd(2021, 1, 1)` is `<Utc as TimeZone>::ymd(&Utc, 2021, 1, 1)` where the first `Utc` is the *type* `Utc` and the second one is the *value* `Utc`.

Comment: I expected it would also work to request `Tz: TimeZone + Default`, and use `Tz::default().ymd(...)`, but it turns out that `chrono::Utc` is not `Default`! I wonder if that's intentional or just an oversight.